# Double dispatch for dynamically typed operators in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, performance, oop, inheritance, double-dispatch

I want to formulate algebraic expressions in such a way that the underlying number types can be exchanged. If you want to, think about complex numbers, big integers, matrices and the likes. For this reason, I'd write either `add(a, b)` or `a.add(b)` instead of `a + b`. In a statically typed language, I'd simply use type-based overloading of the function `add` to implement the various alternatives. But for JavaScript this doesn't work, so I'm looking for alternatives. The executed method depends on the type of *both* operands.

One way which I've come up with would be the following [double dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) mechanism:

1. Write the expression as `a.add(b)`.
2. Implement that method for a given type (e.g. my own `Complex` type, or the built-in `Number` type) in the following way:

   ```
   add: function(that) { that.addComplex(this); }
   ```

   So the method name of the second call encodes the type of one of the operands.
3. Implement specialized methods to deal with all combinations. For example, set

   ```
   Number.prototype.addComplex = function(that)
     { return newComplex(that.real + this, that.imaginary); }
   ```

Let's assume I know all types, so I can ensure all combinations get handled. What has me troubled right now is more the *creation* of these objects.

The above approach relies heavily on virtual method dispatch, so the way I see it it requires some kind of inheritance. No problem with classical constructor functions, but according to [this jsperf](http://jsperf.com/object-creation-mvg) I just did, object creation using constructor functions tends to be slower than object literals. Sometimes slower by quite a large factor, like in the case of Firefox for this example. So I'm reluctant to incur this kind of overhead for *every* e.g. complex-valued numerical intermediate just to make my operator overloading work.

The other approach I tried in this jsperf would be not using a prototype, but instead storing the virtual method as a property of each single object instance. Works quite fast on pretty much all tested browsers, but here I'm worried about the size of the objects. I'm worried about having objects with two actual floating point values but perhaps as much as 50 different member functions just to handle all pairs of operator overloading.

A third approach would be having a single `add` function which somehow inspects the types of its arguments and then makes its decision based on that. Possibly looking up the actual implementation in some list indexed by a combination of some numerical type identifiers. I haven't written this out for a test yet, but this kind of type checking feels pretty slow, and I also have doubts that the JIT compiler will be able to optimize this exotic kind of function dispatch.

Is there some way to trick current JavaScript implementations into doing proper optimized double dispatch with objects which are cheap to create and don't take excessive amounts of memory either?

Comment: Your "Object.create" test needs a `var` for the local variable "pt".  If you do a variant on the "object literal" that uses a local function in a closure, it's even faster than that one (well in one test run anyway).  http://jsperf.com/object-creation-mvg/2

Comment: i cannnot see on this jsper, that "classical constructor" works slowly, also, it seems, you need to remove everything, except "runtest(ctorPoint);", to the setup section, so you will not measure "class" initialization...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third approach looks quite viable:

```
function Complex(re, im) {
    return {type:'c', re:re, im:im }
}
function Real(n) {
    return {type:'r', n:n }
}

funcs = {
    add_c_r: function(a, b) {
        console.log('add compl to real')
    },
    add_r_c: function(a, b) {
        console.log('add real to compl')
    }
}

function add(a, b) {
    return funcs["add_" + a.type + "_" + b.type](a, b);
}

add(Complex(1, 2), Real(5))
add(Real(5), Complex(1, 2))
```

One extra field + one indirection is a reasonable cost.

Comment: Nice solution!!