# How can I refactor the switch case to call methods from a class?

Tags: javascript, node.js, switch-statement

I have a Hero class that extends the Player class, this hero can perform various actions, most of these actions are overridden from the Player class, so far so good.

```
class Hero extends Player {
  constructor(level = 1) {
    super();
    this.level = level;
  }

  // override
  attack() {
    return 'attacking';
  }

  defend() {
    return 'defending';
  }

  walk() {
    return 'walking';
  }

  run() {
    return 'running';
  }

  fly() {
    return 'flying';
  }

  jump() {
    return 'jumping';
  }
}

module.exports = Hero
```

Now I need to call these actions dynamically by sending a parameter, for example, I look for a user in the database and check what the action's type is (integer), if it's 0, execute the **attack()** method, if it's 1, executes the **defend()** method. I created a switch case with all possible cases, however whenever I add a new action, I will have to modify the switch and it gets bigger and bigger. How best to work with this? Knowing that I have to call these methods dynamically with a "type" parameter.

```
const hero = new Hero();
let type = 1; // this type is dynamic and comes from a database API
let result = null;
switch (type) {
    case 0:
        result = hero.attack();
        break;

    case 1:
        result = hero.defend();
        break;

    case 2:
        result = hero.walk();
        break;

    case 3:
        result = hero.run();
        break;

    case 4:
        result = hero.fly();
        break;

    case 5:
        result = hero.jump();
        break;
}

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Hint: double dispatch.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I googled it and couldn't understand it, sorry.

Comment: Another hint: visitor pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can map numbers to functions using an object, which will make it become way smaller (one line each). Here's a simplified example:

```
let actions = {
    1: attack,
    2: defend,
};

actions[type]();
```

Comment: It will really reduce the lines and the result will be the same, it seems like a good alternative.

Answer (score 1):

In case your action types are really defined as successive integers starting from 0 then you may just use an array instead of a map;

```
var actions = [attack, defend, walk, ...],
    type    = 0;
actions[type](); // "attacking"
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of naming the functions as `attack` or `fly`. you can name the function as `type` which you expecting from the db. In the existing context
it was integer so I have implemented using integers.

```js
class Hero {
  constructor(level = 1) {
    this.level = level;
  }

  1() {
    return 'attacking';
  }

  2() {
    return 'defending';
  }

  3() {
    return 'walking';
  }

  4() {
    return 'running';
  }

  5() {
    return 'flying';
  }

  jumping() {
    return 'jumping';
  }
}

const hero = new Hero();
let type = 1; // this type is dynamic and comes from a database API
let result = eval('hero[' + type + ']()');

console.log(result)

type = 'jumping' // this type is dynamic and comes from a database API
result = eval('hero.' + type + '()');

console.log(result)
```

`let result = eval('hero[' + type + ']()');` and  i have generated the function name and evaluated it's value dynamically. these are some of the resources which might help you [double dispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20267196/double-dispatch-for-dynamically-typed-operators-in-javascript) and [dynamic-function-names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905492/dynamic-function-name-in-javascript)

Comment: It is definitely the alternative that shortens the lines, but it is not readable by the programmer an unnamed method :(

Comment: In the context of readability, you can update the values in the DB which is the more readable function name. @viniciussvl

Comment: if i could change the type in the database, would i return the function name instead of returning the integer type?

Comment: yes, returning the function name would be a better idea it will give you more readability. I have updated my answer for your reference.  @viniciussvl